# How does Tkinter handle child widgets when a parent is destroyed/derefenced?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm wondering what is going on here. When I run this program, I notice that the memory from the TestFrame class (200mb or so) is still being used even after I've destroyed it and removed any reference to it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class TestFrame(ttk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.bigDictionary = {'Hello World' + str(num): 'Hello World' + str(num) for num in range(1000000)}
    self.testLabel = ttk.Label(self, text='This is a test Label')
    self.testLabel.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
testFrame = TestFrame(root)
testFrame.grid()
testFrame.destroy()
testFrame = ''
root.mainloop()
```

I then removed the label from being an attribute like so:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.bigDictionary = {'Hello World' + str(num): 'Hello World' + str(num) for num in range(1000000)}
    testLabel = ttk.Label(self, text='This is a test Label')
    testLabel.grid()
```

When I ran this code now I noticed that Python was no longer keeping the memory from the frame around. Can anyone provide some insight on what is going on here?

Comment: You had a circular reference - `self.testLabel` referenced the Label, the Label's `master` referenced the TestFrame.  This means that the objects couldn't be immediately reclaimed as soon as you dropped the `testFrame` reference, because neither object's reference count was zero.  However, they would eventually be reclaimed by a pass of the garbage collector, which exists specifically to find cycles of objects like this with no external references.

Comment: Python also likes to hang onto memory that the OS has allocated for it, because it's easier to re-use memory already allocated than release memory and ask for more memory from the OS.

Comment: @jasonharper So is there a way around this using Tkinter? I ran this as part of a larger program and it doesn't appear to be getting collected. I guess I could pass in a frame object instead of subclassing, but that seems kind of clumsy.